# Yarn Resource Manage didn't allocate containers when asking for containers with different resources

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I used synchronous AMRMClient in application master, using addContainerRequest method of AMRMClient to add container requests, using getMatchingRequests and removeContainerRequest methods of AMRMClient to remove container requests. However, when program add container requests with different resources, Resource Manager no longer allocated any resource to application master and it lead to deadlock. Have somebody once faced such problem?

Comment: I've got very similar problem, the only difference is that I can get one container allocated but no more. By enabling debug log in ResourceManager, I found resource request is indeed sent to RM, but somehow lost during `CapacityScheduler.allocate`'s call to `updateResourceRequests`. Still don't know the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Container request at the same priority should have the same resource requirement for now. A workaround for the problem is to use different resource requirements with different priorities. JIRA issue [YARN-314](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-314) has more discussions about this.

---

The following detailed code analysis applies to Hadoop 2.7.3.

The key to the problem is in `AppSchedulingInfo` which organizes all requests according to priority and resource name:

```java
final Map<Priority, Map<String, ResourceRequest>> requests
```

So for any given priority and resource name, you can have only one `ResourceRequest` which holds the priority, cpu, memory requirements and number of containers.

In `AMRMClientImpl` container requests are kept in the following data structure:

```java
class ResourceRequestInfo {
    ResourceRequest remoteRequest;
    ...
}

Map<Priority, Map<String, TreeMap<Resource, ResourceRequestInfo>>> remoteRequestsTable;
```

So for the same priority and resource name with different resource requirements, you end up with different `ResourceRequest`

When AM calls `AMRMClientImpl.addContainerRequest` for the same resource requirements, it will increase number of containers in previously created instance of `ResourceRequest`. When adding different resource requirements for the same priority and resource name, you end up with different instances of `ResourceRequest`, but only the last one will be kept in `AppSchedulingInfo` for scheduling. That's why container request would get lost and never allocated.