# Can request YARN containers of different resource capabilities in a tight loop?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I am writing a native YARN application following the model of the distributed shell application. In my application master I am requesting two containers using the usual looping as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < appContainerList.size(); ++i)
{
  ContainerRequest containerAsk = setupContainerAskForRM(i);
  amRMClient.addContainerRequest(containerAsk);
  appContainerList.setStatus(i, "requested");      
}
```

As long as the two containers request the same amount of memory, say either 512 or 1000, then shortly after this loop runs I get a callback to the onContainersAllocated method of my AMRMClientAsync.CallbackHandler with a list of two allocated containers that were allocated. This also happens if I ask for more than two containers with the same resource allocation, but I am keeping it to two here so that the demonstration of the issue is simplified.

However, if I make the requests for different capabilities, say one for 512 and the other for 1000, then I also get a callback but only one container is allocated, and I never get a call back for the second container request.

I know that the communication between the AMRMClientAsync and the RM rides on top of heartbeats that are sent every second, so I tried inserting a sleep between the two container requests and now I get two callbacks, each with one allocated container.

Here is my code with a sleep.

```
for (int i = 0; i < appContainerList.size(); ++i)
{
  ContainerRequest containerAsk = setupContainerAskForRM(i);
  amRMClient.addContainerRequest(containerAsk);
  appContainerList.setStatus(i, "requested");
  try
  {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException ex)
  {
    LOG.info("sleep interrupted " + ex);
  } 
}
```

It this correct, is it impossible to request containers with different resource capabilities in a tight loop? Do requests for containers with different resource capabilities require a sleep in between so they don’t end up riding the same heartbeat same communication to the RM?

If so, this seems to mean that if I have many different container types, with different resource capabilities, I have to group them and make sure that requests for different types have at least one heartbeat between them. This is much more complicated than simply requesting the containers in a tight loop without regard to the resource capabilities each one is requesting.

I found a related post here: [post by yihee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116215/yarn-resource-manage-didnt-allocate-containers-when-asking-for-containers-with/38783918#38783918) and a JIRA here: [YARN-314](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-314).

The answer to my question appears to be, as it says in YARN-314:
"Currently, resource requests for the same container and locality are expected to all be the same size." Therefore to request containers of different resource requirements in a tight loop they must have different priorities if the resources requested are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Based on the other references I mentioned, especially YARN-314, I changed the priorities of the containers I requested and now I can request the containers in a tight loop and I get both containers allocated in the same call to my onContainersAllocated callback handler.